# sawtooth generator for MCP1630

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, microchip, error-amplifier

when using MCP1630V to design a buck converter in voltage mode control, is it preferabale to get sawtooth generator from the drive output pin or from the oscillator input pin?

From the timing diagram of this component page 14/26 of the datasheet, I think the sawtooth generator should be fed from the drive output

Please confime it to me